# Set a Display colour profile via Terminal or AppleScript? (Macbook)

Tags: terminal, display, applescript, color

I would like to be able to change the display colour profile of my MacBook, with a view to writing a program that changes the loaded colour profile on a shortcut key-press, or automatically at certain times. Does anyone know of a Terminal or AppleScript command that could load an existing colour profile? I am aware that this could be achieved through UI scripting of the System Preferences application, but I'm not a fan as UI manipulation tends to be slow, messy and unreliable.

I know the .icc colour profiles used are stored at /Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Displays/, but opening one of the .icc files only starts ColorSync Utility, and I can't see an obvious way to load them.

I am using a 2007 MacBook (not Pro or Air), a "Core 2 Duo" 2.16 GHz model, running Snow Leopard version 10.6.8. I am pretty sure f.lux is not supported on Snow Leopard, and I would like more manual control anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Somebody wrote a [customdisplayprofiles](https://github.com/timsutton/customdisplayprofiles) command (in Python) for changing display profiles from the command line. I haven't tried it out, though.