# OSX Change monitor profile by command line

Tags: macos, command-line, color

I'm looking for a away to simulate night shift on older Mac's (10.9) I generated a Monitor Profile with the ColorSync tools. Now I want to change the profile with a terminal command. Manually you do that in System settings > Displays > Color.

Comment: It does rather seem to be re-inventing the wheel... have you considered [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/news/pages/macquickstart/) ?

Comment: Yes, but it has ver poor configuration features. Mainly now time scheduler. Better say only very limited timer.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/268952/using-applescript-to-launch-specific-tabs-in-system-preferences-panes Use similar AppleScript and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/103621/run-applescript-from-bash-script run it from Terminal. You can also see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235019/set-a-display-colour-profile-via-terminal-or-applescript-macbook to see if that utility is updated or not. [edit] the post to update the script that you can think of and need help running it via command line.